# Adding another object to an element that holds object as value

Tags: javascript, object

Hey so I basicly have this example of an input-

```
solve2([
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 500",
    "Bulgaria > Sopot > 800",
    "France > Paris > 2000",
    "Albania > Tirana > 1000",
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 200"
])
```

My idea is that, I want to add these country/cities/cost to an object called destination and the countries to be another object which will hold as elements the city and the cost like this:

```
destination = {
Bulgaria: {Sofia: 500, Sopot: 500},
France: {Paris: 2000},
Albania: {Tirana: 1000}
}
```

I've tried this:

```
function solve2(input)
{
    let destination = {};

    input.forEach(set => {
        let [country, town, cost] = set.split(' > ');
        
        destination[country] = {[town]: cost};
       
        
    });
    console.log(destination);
}
```

But it just seems to be rewriting the old ones with the new ones that come in the input.

Comment: You cannot have same keys in a object, you must use array for this.

Comment: I won't need to have, after I figure this out, I will need to take only the one with the lowest cost for example sofia:200 and sofia:500 i will get the first one since its lower cost.

Comment: @Chrissisbeast why does your output have `sofia: 500` instead of `sofia: 200`. 200 is less than 500 so I'd expect it to be set to 200

Comment: @NickParsons Yeah, thats another problem I need to solve, how to pick the one with the lowest value

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the key in the object first if it does not exist first initialize it and then add respected values into it, like this:

```js
function solve2(input) {
  let destination = {};

  input.forEach(set => {
    let [country, town, cost] = set.split(" > ");
    if (!destination[country]) destination[country] = { [town]: cost };
    else destination[country][town] = cost;
  });
  console.log(destination);
}

solve2([
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 500",
    "Bulgaria > Sopot > 800",
    "France > Paris > 2000",
    "Albania > Tirana > 1000",
    "Bulgaria > Sofia > 200"
])
```

this would work.

Answer (score 2):

You can just reduce your array like that.

```
const result = arr.reduce((destination, value) => {
  const [country, town, cost] = value.split('>').map(it => it.trim());

  destination[country] = destination[country]
    ? { ...destination[country], [town]: cost }
    : { [town]: cost };

  return destination;
}, {});
```

Comment: Also before nice to have sort costs:
```arr.sort((a, b) => b.split(' > ')[2] - a.split(' > ')[2])```
and then reduce

Answer (score 1):

You can use ... spread syntax to copy to original so it doesn't override the existing values

```
function solve2(input)
{
    let destination = {};

    input.forEach(set => {
        let [country, town, cost] = set.split(' > ');
        
        destination[country] = {
            ...destination[country],
            [town]: cost
        };
    });
    console.log(destination);
}
```